# Why the browser is displaying a blank webpage?

Tags: struts, tiles, struts-1

1. my welcome page is `welcome.jsp` listed in `web.xml` file
2. `welcome.jsp` contains a simple form for submission to an action which is mapped by `struts-config.xml` file
3. all the mappings are correct as the form goes for submission to an action a blank page is displayed by the browser? I don't know what's the problem.
4. the address bar shows the correct URL which is hitting the correct action but still blank page is displayed.

I am providing my `welcome.jsp` , `struts-config.xml` file , action here in the snippet

**`struts-config.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC 
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" 
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="login1" type="aditya.bean.LoginBean"/>       
    </form-beans>
     
   <!-- <global-forwards>
    </global-forwards>--> 
    
    <!-- Action Mappings -->
    <action-mappings>

        <action path="/login" 
                type="aditya.action.LoginAction" 
                name="login1"
                parameter="method"
                />
                
        <forward name="loginadmin" path="/jsp/adminwel.jsp" />
        <forward name="loginuser" path="tuser"/>       

    </action-mappings>
    <controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor"/>
<!--  <message-resources  parameter="ApplicationResources"  null="false"  />  -->
    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin">
    <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-def.xml"/>
    <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true"/>
   </plug-in>
   
</struts-config>
```

**`welcome.jsp`:**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    
 <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="h" %> 
 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<h:form action="login.do" method="post">
<table border="5" bgcolor="cyan" align="center">
<tr><td>USER ID</td><td><h:text property="uid"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>PASSWORD</td><td><h:password property="pass"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><h:submit property="method" value="login"/></td></tr>
</table>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**`LoginAction`:**

```java
package aditya.action;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;
import aditya.bean.LoginBean;



public class LoginAction extends DispatchAction {
    
    public ActionForward login(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException
     {
         LoginBean loginBean=(LoginBean)form;
         System.out.println("in action-");
         
         if(loginBean.getUid().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")&&loginBean.getPass().equalsIgnoreCase("admin"))
          {
             return mapping.findForward("loginadmin");
          }
         else
          {
             return mapping.findForward("loginuser");
          }
        
     }
}
```

Why the browser is displaying a blank webpage?

IDE Used --> Eclipse

Comment: A [mcve] is required.

Comment: @Roman C Please help me debug my problem....... Please provide any additional information you Need to Help me with ???

Comment: Would you tell me how did you build your app? How did you deploy it? Do you have any errors in the log files?

Comment: @Roman C                                                                                                                
 (1) From where I can access log files ??                                                       
 (2) Please tell about in which directory I can access log files ???                                                                                                       
 (3) I am using Eclipse to build my Project.. & used tomcat to deploy my project ..

Comment: What java version? What Tomcat version? Can you show me the contents of WEB-INF/lib in the .war file? Can you post web.xml, tiles.xml?

Comment: @Roman C  Actually I am taking two input values uid and pass from a form present inside a welcome.jsp (index page) and then these values are sent to an appropriate Action Mapped in Struts-config.xml file  for further processing.. A seperate bean named "LoginBean" is populated with uid and pass values..  Finally Based on uid and pass values appropriate view is choosen from <forward> tag in Struts-config.xml file and then sent to appropriate jsp file.... The Main Problem is that Whenever the Action is invoked at Form submission Browser Displays A "'BLANK PAGE"

Comment: @Roman C I have already posted Struts-config.xml , welcome.jsp , Action class in the Answers but on your deamand i am posting web.xml file in my answers please go through it......

Comment: I am using java SE1.8 and tomcat 7 in my project.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blank page is displayed because *none* of the results returned to the browser from the action class. In the `login()` action the code should return `ActionForward` instance. But it returns `null`.

Define global forwards:

```xml
<global-forwards>
  <forward name="error" path="/error.jsp"/>       
</global-forwards>
```

Action code:

```java
ActionForward result;
if(loginBean.getUid().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")&&loginBean.getPass().equalsIgnoreCase("admin"))
{
  result = mapping.findForward("loginadmin");
  if (result == null) 
    return mapping.findForward("error");
} 
else {
  result = mapping.findForward("loginuser");
  if (result == null) 
    return mapping.findForward("error");
}
return result;
```

Comment: Shuold i have to create a seperate "error.jsp" page ??

Comment: No, pick one that you have.

Comment: @ Roman C Problem Resolved .... Actually I have cleaned the tomcat work directory and changed the directory structure of my project a little bit .and provided correct paths to my jsp files wooahhh it worked ..... project is running .... Thanks for the help brother...

Comment: You can check on this answer, the checkbox is on the left of it.